# How to generate multiple files with sencha CMD

Tags: javascript, extjs, build, extjs4, sencha-cmd

Iam using Sencha cmd v4.0 and I want to generate multiple compressed and minified files.

For now **sencha app build** generates single app.js files.

But I need 2 files: all-compressed.js (which contains all extjs framework files + product generic files) and
my-compressed.js (which contains my product specific views and controller files)

Is there any possibility to do this?

```
workspaceDir

    |
    +->packages
        +->PROJECT
            +->.sencha
             |
             +-> .sencha
             +-> build
             +-> overrides
             +-> resources
             +-> src
                +-> PROJECT folder + common folder files
             build.xml
             package.json
```

Comment: In order to get these artfacts you need to modify the ant tasks. Simple quick hack, move all files which should belong to my-compressed.js inside an ext-js package. Run sencha package build inside the package folder - and you will get by default inside the build folder a compressed and debug version of the package. You can further customize settings inside the package.json or sencha.cfg - depends on your setup. Everything else (all-compressed.js) should stay inside the app.

Comment: @devbnz thanks for your response, I have added my folder structure above. Iam able to generate js file inside build folder. But the file being generated contains common folder contents. Keeping this folder structure, is it possible to include contents only from "PROJECT folder" and to exclude from  "common folder"?

Comment: Yes that should be possible by modifing the build.xml or a hook file inside the .sencha folder. I would suggest that you take a look inside these files, often you will find comments which will describe what you can customize there. On top i would suggest to look up how to custimize or build js files using ant. Sencha CMD is basically a wrapper around ant. But thats the reason why i moved away. For your setup as far as i understand it - i would move everything into an ext js package, build everything individually and then concat it later how you need it.

Comment: @devbnz Excluding the folder worked perfectly using "exclude
           -file="  command inside Build.xml, thanks a lot for the guide line, now iam able to generate file with contents specific to my product (my-compressed.js). 
But still iam not getting how to generate the other file (all-compressed.js) paralelly out of same directory, while running  "sencha package build"