# ExtJs MVC Application won't load

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am currently trying to start an ExtJs MVC application that I created, integrated into another application. For unclear reasons it refuses to start, nor does it give any reasonable message as to why its happening, looking at the code below, I was able to determine that the `init` function runs to the end, but not the `launch` or `beforeLaunch`. Also `Das.SubApp` extends `Ext.app.Controller`.

```
   this.subApp = Ext.create('Das.SubApp', {
        appFolder: '/Scripts/app/das/FBrowser',
        name: 'FBrowser',
        controllers: ['BrowerController'],
        dependencies: {
            css: [],
            js: []
        },
        init: function() {console.log("initialized")},
        beforeLaunch: function() {
            console.log("Before launch");
        },
        launch: function () {
            console.log("launched library");
           }
```

Here is code from the BrowserController:

```
Ext.define('FBrowser.controller.BrowserController',{
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
views: ['browser.tree_dir',...],
stores: [...],
requires: ['FBrowser.Utilities'],

init: function() {

    this.control({..})
```

Anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

EDIT: Ok, so I seem to have found part of the issue, It appears that the application path isn't being set, I still don't understand why that is though, shouldn't the `appFolder` point to the right place?

Comment: What console message from the browser says ?

Comment: I get the `initialized` message from above, I don't get any other messages, no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easy;

`Ext.app.Controller` does not have

- appFolder
- name
- beforeLaunch

and if you initialize it this way it wan't call the launch method cause this is all done or better said belongs to the `Ext.app.Application` Controller. Also note that you can only have one active `Ext.app.Application` instance or you will mess up the `EventBus` (override the bus of the first `Ext.app.Application`). And even if you add these properties (appFolder, name) they do nothing at all cause the they are only used within the `Ext.app.Application` which is derived from `Ext.app.Controller`

**The solution**

`Das.SubApp` need to be `Ext.app.Application` (don't extend if not really needed cause you can have only one instance active anyway).

You may also be interested in **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939305/an-extjs-app-calling-another-extjs-app)** answer or **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645180/using-more-than-one-controller-with-extjs-4-mvc)**

Comment: Ah, that looks reasonable. I assumed that `Ext.app.Controller` must work since there are other application that use `Das.Subapp`, but looking more carefully I noticed that mine is the first one to use ExtJs MVC where `appFolder` and `name` are relevant.